# Actionbar compatibility two sets of menu dots

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I have been trying to add an action bar to my application.

It is working but not as nice as I would hope.  The problem is that I have two sets of three dots for accessing the menu.  In the Action bar itself, and along the bottom where my soft keys are.  This is the same on a Nexus 4 and a Moto X.  Both sets of buttons work.  On a Note 8 I have no buttons at all (should I expect the top action bar ones?), but the (physical) menu key does what it is supposed to do.

Extracts from Manifest

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
```

login_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/login"
          android:title="@string/menu_login"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Extracts from Login.java

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.login_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            handleLogin();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This is how it looks, any assistance appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Say Goodbye to the Menu Button blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html), you need to add a `targetSdkVersion` of 14 or higher:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"
          android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Note it is a good practice to always set your target SDK version to the highest version you have tested your app on as it is the target SDK version that sets up compatibility modes such as what you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you worked as you suggested.  I would never have found this on my own.